# Проблема с подключением PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, apache2

Добрый день! Перехожу на PDO, столкнулся со странной ситуацией, есть скрипт следующего вида:

```
include 'db.php';
function addGroup($group_name){

$stmt=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO group_back SET name_group=? ');
$stmt=$pdo->execute(array($group_name));

}
```

При обращении к функции addGroup сыпится ошибка:

```
Undefined variable:pdo
```

Вот содержимое db.php

```
$host = '*****';
$db   = '*****';
$user = '*****';
$pass = '*****';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

сам скрипт db.php отрабатывает( проверил банальным запросом к таблице и выводом результата запроса ).
Я так понимаю по какой-то причине php не получает переменную при инициализаци 
скрипта db.php...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно передать переменную `$pdo` как аргумент функции или сделать её глобальной с помощью `global`.

```
function addGroup($pdo, $group_name){
    $stmt=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO group_back SET name_group=? ');
    $stmt=$pdo->execute(array($group_name));
}
```

Вызывать функцию так:

```
addGroup($pdo, $group_name);
```

[Область видимости переменной](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Спасибо, как раз прочитал внимательно доку про область видимости.